# angular 7 ngmodel component and form binding

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-ngmodel

I have stuck in form binding between component and template. I want to implement REST API for post method

component.html

```
  <div class="container custom-container">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <h3 class="mb-3 text-center">Create Employee</h3>

<div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="employeeDetails.name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="employeeDetails.email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
</div>


<div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="employeeDetails.phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" (click)="addEmployee()">Create Employee</button>
</div>
```

Component.ts

```
   import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
   import { Router } from '@angular/router';
   import { RestApiService } from "../shared/rest-api.service";
   @Component({
      selector: 'app-employee-create',
      templateUrl: './employee-create.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./employee-create.component.css']
   })
  export class EmployeeCreateComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() employeeDetails = { name: '', email: '', phone: 0 }

  constructor(
     public restApi: RestApiService, 
     public router: Router
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() { }

  addEmployee(dataEmployee) {
      this.restApi.createEmployee(this.employeeDetails).subscribe((data: {}) => {
      this.router.navigate(['/employees-list'])
     })
    }
  }
```

I want pass form value in createEmployee function. So that I can access this on server side.

Comment: Are you saying the this.employeeDetails value is not getting binded to the form value?If so, Did you try checking the value in this.employeeDetails ? maybe do a console.log(this.employeeDetails) and check your console for the values

Comment: @PreethiRajaraman I have comment service api and console.log(this.employeeDetails) I am geeting {"name":"","email":"","phone":0}

Answer (score 0):

Your method `addEmployee` doesnt need any argument because you are using template driven approach to bind your form data and same time your are not passing any data from the html too. change your method signature to `addEmployee() { //logic }`. Once you click the button it will trigger this method and get you the current values bind to the object

Comment: I have also used without parameters

Comment: Are those inputs inside a <form></form> tag?

Answer (score 0):

Use a console.log to check form value, 
Seems like form values are properly bound. 
Try stringify the object before passing to http post

```
JSON.stringify(this.employeeDetails)
```

Comment: I have use this its contain name with blank

Comment: Form values are properly bound in object employeeDetails. I think you might be having issue in your service.

Comment: I have comment service code and console.log used response is {"name":"","email":"","phone":0}

Comment: you have to enter name,email & phone in the form field then click create employee button. see - {name: "dasf", email: "fasd", phone: "123"}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212968/discussion-between-sudhir-and-jithin).